# String to bytes encryption cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken

Tags: python, flask, url, encryption, cryptography

I am passing encrypted text to the url as a string and after retrieving I am converting the type to bytes but I am getting this error cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken

```
@app.route('/Friend/<string:hostname>')
def Friend(hostname):
    hostname = bytes(hostname, 'utf-8')
    decrypted_hostname = f.decrypt(hostname).decode()
    print(decrypted_hostname)
    return render_template('friend.html')
```

Comment: yes hostname str in route is encrypted with same key of fernet

Comment: can you share hostname encryption code

Comment: `# key and f are global variables
key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)

host_name = getHostName()

encrypted_hostname = f.encrypt(host_name.encode())`

and then I am storing the encrypted_hostname in the sqlite database

Comment: before storing in database, you are decoding `encrypted_hostname` in string because when you encrypted , it  become `bytes` so check if you  are decoding `encrypted_hostname.decode()` before storing , other best way is to check hostname value in database it should be string not bytes like `b''`